# Java- Segundo número mayor

Tags: java

Hola tengo un problema en java que me pide sacar el promedio, número mayor, segundo número mayor y segundo número menor, cómo podría obtener el segundo número mayor y segundo número menor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int edad1=0, edad2=0, edad3=0;
    float mediaEdad;

    edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 1"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
    edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 2"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
    edad3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 3"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));

    int suma = edad1 +edad2 + edad3;

    mediaEdad = (float) suma/3;

    if (edad1 > edad2) {
        if (edad1 > edad3) {
            System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad3);
        }
    } else if (edad2 > edad3) {
        System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad3);
    }

    System.out.println("La edad promedio es: " +mediaEdad);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int edad1=0, edad2=0, edad3=0;
    float mediaEdad;

    edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 1"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
    edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 2"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
    edad3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 3"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));

    int suma = edad1 +edad2 + edad3;

    mediaEdad = (float) suma/3;

    if (edad1 > edad2) {
        if (edad1 > edad3) {
            System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad3);
        }
    } else if (edad2 > edad3) {
        System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad3);
    }

    System.out.println("La edad promedio es: " +mediaEdad);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es encontrar el segundo mayor o segundo menor, sera el del medio, creo que podrías intentarlo así. Como dijeron modificando un poco tus condicionales.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int edad1=0, edad2=0, edad3=0;
float mediaEdad;

edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 1"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 2"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
edad3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 3"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));

int suma = edad1 +edad2 + edad3;

mediaEdad = (float) suma/3;

if (edad1 > edad2 && edad1>edad3) {
    System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad1);
    if(edad2>edad3){
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad2);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad3);
    }else{
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad3);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad2);
    }
} else if (edad2 > edad1 && edad2>edad3) {
    System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad2);
    if(edad1>edad3){
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad1);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad3);
    }else{
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad3);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad1);
    }
}  else if(edad3 > edad1 && edad3>edad2) {
    System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad3);
    if(edad1>edad2){
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad1);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad2);
    }else{
        System.out.println("el medio es: " + edad2);
        System.out.println("el menor es: " + edad1);
    }
} 

System.out.println("La edad promedio es: " +mediaEdad);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tu logica de programacion esta bien pero te recomiendo que compares los 3 numeros por ejemplo:

```
if (edad1 > edad2 && edad1 > edad3 ) {
        System.out.println("El mayor es: " + edad1);
} else if (edad2 > edad3 && edad2 > edad1  ) {
    System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad2);
} else {
    System.out.println("el mayor es: " + edad3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con este código puedes obtener fácilmente el mayor, menor y el de en medio, de un total de 3 números.

Con `stream.sorted()` ordenas los números, luego usas `stream.toArray()` para volverlo un arreglo. El número menor quedó en `numeros[0]`, el de enmedio en `numeros[1`] y el mayor en `numeros[2]`;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 1"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
        int edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 2"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));
        int edad3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("persona 3"  + "\n Ingresa tu edad"));

        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(edad1, edad2, edad3);
        Object[] numeros = stream.sorted().toArray();
        System.out.println("Número de en medio: " + numeros[1]);
        System.out.println("Número menor: " + numeros[0]);
        System.out.println("Número mayor: " + numeros[2]);
    }
}
```